# Python multi threaded program exit code -1073741819

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm writing a desktop client for omegle and for the first time I'm dealing with multithreaded programming. My program (python itself it seems) exits with code -1073741819.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *

import os
import sys

from python_omegle.randomchat import RandomChat
from python_omegle.chatevent import ChatEvent

import threading
import enum



class ChatState(enum.Enum):
    NONE = 1
    WAITING = 2
    CONNECTED = 3
    CLOSING = 4
    OPENING = 5
    QUIT = 6

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.container = QWidget()
        self.container.setLayout(self.layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)

        self.topics = QLineEdit()
        self.output = QTextEdit()
        self.message = QLabel()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.input = QLineEdit()

        self.layout1.addWidget(self.topics)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.output)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.message)
        self.layout2.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout2.addWidget(self.input)
        self.layout1.addLayout(self.layout2)

        self.output.setReadOnly(True)
        self.input.setFocus()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_pressed)

        self.chat_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.chat)
        self.chat_state = ChatState.NONE
        self.chat_thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.chat_state = ChatState.QUIT
        event.accept()

    def on_window_close(self):
        self.chat_state = ChatState.QUIT

    def on_button_pressed(self):
        state = self.button.text()
        if state == "Start":
            self.chat_state = ChatState.OPENING
            self.button.setText("Stop")
        elif state == "Stop":
            self.button.setText("Really?")
        elif state == "Really?":
            self.button.setText("Start")
            self.chat_state = ChatState.CLOSING

    def chat(self):
        chat = RandomChat()
        while True:
            if self.chat_state == ChatState.OPENING:
                chat.start()
                self.chat_state = ChatState.WAITING
                self.output.clear()
            elif self.chat_state == ChatState.CLOSING:
                chat.disconnect()
                self.message.setText("You have disconnected.")
                self.chat_state = ChatState.NONE
            elif self.chat_state == ChatState.WAITING:
                while True:
                    event, argument = chat.get_event()
                    if event == ChatEvent.CHAT_READY:
                        self.message.setText("You're now chatting with a random partner.")
                        self.chat_state = ChatState.CONNECTED
                        break
                    elif event == ChatEvent.CHAT_WAITING:
                        self.message.setText("Looking for someone you can chat with...")
            elif self.chat_state == ChatState.CONNECTED:
                while True:
                    event, argument = chat.get_event()
                    if event == ChatEvent.GOT_MESSAGE:
                        message = argument
                        self.output.append("Partner: {}".format(message))
                    elif event == ChatEvent.CHAT_ENDED:
                        self.message.setText("Partner has disconnected.")
                        self.button.setText("Start")
                        self.chat_state = ChatState.NONE
                        break
            elif self.chat_state == ChatState.QUIT:
                break

def GUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("oclient")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

I suspect the error incurs because I change the value of `MainWindow.chat_state` both in the main thread and the `chat_thread`. The reason why I need a multithreaded approach is because the function `RandomChat.get_event` does not return until at least one event is available.

The omegle api can be found here: https://github.com/coal0/python-omegle  I'm also using pyqt5.

Comment: This is a lot of code – please help us help you and provide sufficient information so that volunteers do *not* have to read/understand it all. See the [mcve] and [help] pages for details. Please [edit] your question to clearly define *under which conditions* the program crashes *in what way*. Does it crash during startup? Is a certain action required? Does it crash completely, or enter a broken state and must be killed? Please also indicate whether you are running this on Windows – `-1073741819` is the code for an Access violation in Windows, but meaningless on Linux/MacOS.

Comment: I apologize, I'll update the question as soon as I can with more details and maybe less code. Also I imagined that that was too much code to post, but in this case this is the entire program and can be tested as is.